# Finding a faster function then "gethostbyname"?

Tags: php

I run a script under xampp with a mysqlDB.

I check if a domainname has an ip.

The problem is, that I have to check over 100000 domain names from a MySQL_DB.

The function "gethostbyname" works great, but my solution is too slow.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db_res)) { // get the DB domainnames entrys
    if (empty($row['status'])) {  
      $items[] =  $row['domainnames'];
    } 
    foreach ($items AS $domain) { 
        if ( gethostbyname($domain) != $domain ) {
            do somthing.....
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get it faster?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when your while loop iterates, it uses the $items from the last iteration - which will waste time - so please try this version (putting the foreach into the if:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db_res)) { // get the DB domainnames entrys
  if (empty($row['status'])) {  
    $items[] =  $row['domainnames'];
    foreach ($items AS $domain) { 
      if ( gethostbyname($domain) != $domain ) {
        do somthing.....
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach()` loop inside of your `while()` loop is simply a bad idea.  Think about it. 
 As you iterate the result set, `$items` swells and swells -- this means that the `foreach()` will have to work longer and longer and longer.

Ultimately, if you need to process the `gethostbyname()` value for the next task in your script, you should be storing that value at the same time that you INSERT the entry into your table the first time -- perhaps the new column can be `host`.

The smart money is not to call `gethostbyname()` 100000 times; have the value ready when you SELECT it.

---

Beyond the above logic, I don't see the need to declare an array with a single element/string, then iterate it.

In fact, your query should contain a WHERE clause that excludes rows that have a `null`/`0`/blank `status` value AND includes rows that have a `host` (new column) value that matches `$domain` so that php doesn't have to bother any qualifying/disqualifying conditions.

```
foreach ($db_res as $row) {  // yes, you can simply iterate the result object
    // do whatever with the associative string elements (e.g. $row['domainnames'])
    // ...you know this is a string and not an array, right? -^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers.
With your assistance i was able to reduce the procedure to:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db_res))
{
        $domain =  $row['domainnames'];
       if ( gethostbyname($domain) != $domain ) {
    do somthing.....;
      }
    else{
do somthing.....;
    }
  }
```

it feels a little bit faster but not enough.
@mickmackusa i catch now only the empty "status" fields:

```
$db_res = mysqli_query ($db_link, "select domainnames FROM domaintable WHERE status = ''")
```